# How to enable or disable the submit button thru radio button in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```
<nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
              <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
            </nz-radio-group>
<button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [disabled]="disableSubmitBtn()">
  <span translate>Submit</span>
</button>
```

When it select the `passed` it should `enabled` the submit button if it select the `failed` it should disabled the submit button

Comment: also you are using formControlname and ngModel together which is not the correct way. you should use one.

Comment: @Mridul if I remove the formControlname and ngModel there will be ann error

Comment: You need to keep one based on your requirement :)

Comment: okay thanks.. @Mridul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a small change in your code

```
<nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
          <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
          <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
        </nz-radio-group>
<button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [disabled]="radioValue == 'failed'">
    <span translate>Submit</span>
</button>
```

Comment: how'bout when you apply it on ts?

Comment: in that case you need to take a variable on your ts file example: isDisabled: boolean; and on your html [disabled]="isDisabled" by default it will be false. then under ngModelChange function you need to check the radio button value if radioValue is failed then you can make isDisabled = true;

Answer (score 2):

You just change following line

```
 <button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [disabled]="!radioValue ? 'disabled': null">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
<nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
              <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
            </nz-radio-group>
<button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [disabled]="radioValue == 'passed' ? 'false' : 'true'">
  <span translate>Submit</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may asssign true or false value to radio button to identify pass or fail. And use this condition to enable or disable button.

```
<nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
              <label nz-radio nzValue="true">Passed</label>
              <label nz-radio nzValue="false">Failed</label>
            </nz-radio-group>
<button class="mr-1" nz-button nzType="primary" type="button" [disabled]="nzValue" >
  <span translate>Submit</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and efficient way to achieve this is to use custom validators in angular forms.

```
import { ValidationErrors, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomValidator{
    static checkIfPassed (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        if (control.value == 'passed') {
            return { shouldbepassed: true }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use this validator in you angular forms.

```
passed: ['', [Validators.required, checkIfPassed]],
failed: ['', [Validators.required, checkIfPassed]],
```